# Why does this return more than two values?

Tags: python, function

```
def animal_crackers(text):
   for [word1, word2] in text.split():
        if word1[0]==word2[0]:
            return true
        else:
            pass

animal_crackers('Levelheaded Llama')
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bfc977603445> in <module>()
      5         else:
      6             pass
----> 7 animal_crackers('Levelheaded Llama')

<ipython-input-21-bfc977603445> in animal_crackers(text)
      1 def animal_crackers(text):
----> 2    for [word1, word2] in text.split():
      3         if word1[0]==word2[0]:
      4             return true
      5         else:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`text.split()` returns `['Levelheaded', 'Llama']`, so we get:

```
for [word1, word2] in ['Levelheaded', 'Llama']:
    if word1[0]==word2[0]:
        return true
    else:
        pass
```

Now since we know we have a loop over a list of two elements, we can unroll the loop like this:

```
# First iteration
[word1, word2] = 'Levelheaded'
if word1[0]==word2[0]:
    return true
else:
    pass

# Second iteration
[word1, word2] = 'Llama'
if word1[0]==word2[0]:
    return true
else:
    pass
```

Now something like `[word1, word2] = 'Levelheaded'` will treat the string like a list of characters, but since the words contain more than two characters, you get the error.

Since you don't actually want to loop over anything, you should get rid of the for loop and just write:

```
[word1, word2] = text.split()
```

Comment: It should be noted that `[word1, word2] = text.split()` will cause the exact same error in case `text` contains more than one whitespace,  and the opposite error if it contains no whitespaces at all

Comment: @DeepSpace Sure, but in that case that would be expected, no? As I read it, OP was confused about the error specifically because `text.split()` should return two elements for the given input. I don't think OP expected the code to work for inputs with more or less than one space. In other words: with `[word1, word2] = text.split()` the code does what the OP expected the original to do: compare the first letters of the two words in the string or cause an error if there are less or more than two words. That's my interpretation of the question anyway.

Comment: @sepp2k that's exactly right, the code is meant for 2 word strings only thus only one white space is expected.

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns a list of strings, the edge case being a list with a single string in case the string does not contain the string used as separator.

By saying `for [word1, word2] in text.split()` you are essentially expecting it to return a list of lists, like the following example:

```
for [word1, word2] in [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]:
    print(word1, word2)
```

will output

```
a b
c d
```

You have two options:

- Grab each element individually:

  ```
  for word in 'Levelheaded Llama'.split():
      print(word)
  ```
- Use unpacking (only if you **know** for sure `text` will always have a single whitespace, or if you expect to get an error otherwise):

  ```
  word1, word2 = text.split()
  ```

Comment: It should be `for [word1, word2] in [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`, you missed a closing bracket.

Comment: @thelogicalkoan fixed

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is that you try to assign one value to two variables, here `text.split()` is `['Levelheaded', 'Llama']` and so first elements of elements you'll be iterating over will be `'Levelheaded'` and you try to assign in to two variables `word1` and `word2`.

Instead you could assign them without iterating, also change `true` to `True`.

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    word1, word2 = text.split()
    if word1[0] == word2[0]:
        return True

print(animal_crackers('Levelheaded Llama')) # -> True
```